# Отображение опций в Go

Tags: golang

При установке флагов через flag.String() в справке потом показывается после названия флага принимаемый тип string.
Вопрос: как убрать из справки эту инфу о типе string, чтобы осталось только название флага и заданное мной его описание? Мне нужен вид как для flag.Bool().

Comment: И сразу вопрос: почему вы не хотите использовать буль?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пишите свой собственный `Usage`.  Самый тупой вариант:

```golang
func main() {
    flag.Usage = func() {
        fmt.Fprintf(flag.CommandLine.Output(), "Usage of %s:\n", os.Args[0])
        PrintDefaults(flag.CommandLine)
    }

    // …
}

func PrintDefaults(fs *flag.FlagSet) {
    fs.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
        var _, usage = flag.UnquoteUsage(f)
        var s = "  -" + f.Name + "\n    \t"
        s += strings.ReplaceAll(usage, "\n", "\n    \t")

        _, _ = fmt.Fprintln(fs.Output(), s)
    })
}
```

Результат:

```sh
$ ./tmp.bin --help
```

```
Usage of tmp.bin:
  -bbool
        bbool is a boolean flag
  -fstring
        fstring is a string flag
exit status 2
```